# What to do if my BitCoin Address is only 33 digits?

Tags: address-generation

I noticed that BitCoin addresses usually are equal to 34 digits and/or characters.
I decided to get an extra address and was a bit hesitant to use it since it's 1 digit or character short, is this usable or should I just get another address instead?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [wiki page on Bitcoin addresses](https://en.bitcoin.it/wiki/Address) mentions that addresses van be of length 27-34. So an address of 33 characters long is perfectly usable.